# executing command on vagrant-mounted

Tags: vagrant, upstart

I'm trying to run a command after a share is mounted with vagrant. bu I've never written an upstart script before. What I have so far is

```
start on vagrant-mounted

script
  if [ "$MOUNTPOINT" = "/vagrant" ]
     then
         env CMD="echo $MOUNTPOINT mounted at $(date)"
  elif [ "$MOUNTPOINT" = "/srv/website" ]
     then
         env CMD ="echo execute command"
  fi
end script

exec "$CMD >> /var/log/vup.log"
```

of course that's not the actual script I want to run but I haven't gotten that far yet but the structure is what I need. My starting point has been this [article](http://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount/). I've had a different version that was simply

```
echo $MOUNTPOINT mounted at `date`>> /var/log/vup.log
```

that version did write to the log. 
Trying to use init-checkconf faile with `failed to ask Upstart to check conf file`